# How to get all text in table with Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium

I am using C# and tried with this code to get all text from a table in Selenium.

```
IWebElement table_element = driver.FindElement(By.id("testTable"));
List<IWebElement> tr_collection=table_element.FindElements(By.Xpath("id('testTable')/tbody/tr"));
```

And this error occurs:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

I tried with another method, but the error continues to appear. How to resolved this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use 
`IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>`instead of `List<IWebElement>`

Answer (score 1):

As @Pranav demonstrated that's how you use explicit types, however you can always use `var` too.

For example:

```
var tr_collection = table_element.FindElements(By.Xpath("id('testTable')/tbody/tr"));
```

Comment: Thanks. It's useful.